# Ionic for each observable firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, observable

How to loop through each of the object ?

I trying to listen for firebase changes, so far it manage to detect if there is a push from firebase, problem is at view the HTML.

Where I do wrong ?

Much Appreciate

ping-list.ts

```
    pingList() {
          this.ping.getPingList()
          .subscribe((data) => {
               this.ping_list = data;
               console.log(this.ping_list);

          });
     }
```

*note: console.log(this.ping_list) I can see the object printed in the console, and if there is changes on the data (manually change from firebase console) it will print again, so I guess the observable is working.

ping.ts (provider)

```
getPingList():Observable<any> {
      return new Observable(observer => {
           firebase.database().ref('pings/_list')
           .orderByValue().limitToLast(10)
           .on('value',
                (snapshot) => {
                     observer.next(snapshot.val());
                },
                (err) => {
                     console.log(err);
                }
           );
      });
 }
```

ping-list.html

```
     <button ion-item *ngFor="let a_ping of ping_list">
           {{ a_ping.title }}
      </button>
```

the firebase data looks like this:

```
"pings" : {
 "_list" : {
  "-KmjxLuZWIE72D_syD73" : {
    "date_updated" : 1497600717098,
    "desc" : "ping server 1",
    "title" : "ping 1"
  },
  "-Kmk0x-3OI0FP-TYxC3W" : {
    "date_updated" : 1497601921866,
    "desc" : "ping server 2",
    "title" : "ping 2"
  }
},
```

give me this error

```
Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

I guess the angular cant loop over the ping_list ? or is there anyway to convert the object to array ? I did try to console.log(this.ping_list.length) its undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahhh i got it by this way,

```
 pingList() {
      console.log('ionViewDidLoad PingListPage');
      this.ping.getPingList()
      .subscribe((data) => {
           this.ping_list = [];
           for (var key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                     console.log(key + " -> " + data[key]);
                     this.ping_list.push(data[key]);
                }
           }

      });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post isn't too clear, but as far as I understand `console.log(this.ping_list);` prints correctly that you have received a push notification but the template doesn't update.

You could enforce the template update by having it explicitly into angular's zone.

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class YourPage {

  constructor(private zone:NgZone, ...) {
    ...
  }

  pingList() {
        this.ping.getPingList()
        .subscribe((data) => {
             this.zone.run(() => {
               this.ping_list = data;
               console.log(this.ping_list);
             }
        });
  }
```

You can learn more about `ngZone` and how that can help in [this blog](https://www.joshmorony.com/understanding-zones-and-change-detection-in-ionic-2-angular-2/).

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, I edit my question. Please check again, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash's function [_.forIn()](https://lodash.com/docs/#forIn) may be what you are searching for